# What is seedings in grouping the teams in cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket, terminology, tournaments, cricket-world-cup

I've noticed in the T20 World Cup 2012, that India, Pakistan, Australia and South Africa were placed in the same group for the Super8 stage. All these teams have won all the league matches in the group stages. I have heard that the grouping for the Super8 stage is done by a method called 'seedings'.

What is it?
What is the need of it?
Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seedings are based on the rankings of the each of the participating nation at the cut off point.

The seeding is done so that teams entering the next round (irrespective of where they finish) know which venue they will be headed to. The main reason this was done was for the fans. Now the fans, especially the ones that come from a foreign nation, can choose their itinerary well in advance and they do not need to wait for results of other matches or where their team end up in the preliminary group.

Answer (score 5):

Ten of the teams in the ICC Twenty20 Cricket World Cup are "seeded" teams. They are the 10 governing bodies of the ICC and known as "test teams" and they are automatic entries into the ICC T20 Cricket World Cup.

These 10 teams are split up by the ICC into four groups. Within each group, the teams are ranked (**seeded**) **according to the previous season's performance.**

The teams are seeded based on the following stats (again, from the previous season), listed in order of priority...

1. Number of points
2. If points are equal, number of wins
3. If wins are equal, net run rate
4. If net run rate is equal, bowling strike rate
5. If bowling strike rate is equal, the head-to-head match

[Source](http://sports.ndtv.com/icc-world-twenty20/about/item/196661-world-t20-2012-format-of-the-tournament)

Comment: This not correct, your source is wrong. The source you've referenced lists Pakistan twice to make the 10 nations. There are currently 9 Test playing nations only. Zimbabwe are the 10th seeds who qualify by being members of the ICC governing body. They do not currently play Test Cricket.